# Rally query error when fetching RecycleBinEntry type: "Not able to parse artifact type: recyclebinentry"

Tags: c#, rally

While working on fetching data in Rally I am receiving an error when trying to query for artifact type 'RecycleBinEntry'. The exact error message states, "Not able to parse artifact type: recyclebinentry". I have used approach to get data for other types of artifacts including hierarchicalrequirements and defects. I wonder if this is because the artifact is listed as a non-creation type in the [RallyAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp). When I execute a query directly on the API site I get results as expected.

```
  Request reqDeletesRequest = new Request("RecycleBinEntry");
  reqDeletesRequest.Fetch = new List<string> { "ObjectID", "DeletionDate", "Type", "ID" };
  reqDeletesRequest.Limit = 2500;
  reqDeletesRequest.Query = new Query("DeletionDate", Query.Operator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
  reqDeletesRequest.Workspace = Settings.WorkspaceRef; // This path is correct
  QueryResult qrCompletedDefectsResults = restApi.Query(reqDeletesRequest);
```

Comment: What version of WSAPI are you using? RecycleBinEntry is a documented endpoint only in WSAPI v2.0 or higher.

Comment: Ah there it is! I am on a previous version so will have to update that reference. I knew this was supposed to work so was getting frustrated. Thanks for your help sir!

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a simple matter of having an older version of the Web Service API referenced in my project, a simple mistake, my thanks to [user4211235](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4211235/user4211235) for reminding me of the possibility.